# Java Multiple ResourceBundles

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I want to load multiple property files from various packages as ResourceBundle. Can I achieve that in Java

Answer (score 3):

Extend `java.util.PropertyResourceBundle` and call `setParent`.

Comment: private class ParentResourceHoleder extends ResourceBundle
 {
  
 @Override
 public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
 }
 
 @Override
 protected void setParent(ResourceBundle parent) {  
    
        super.setParent(parent);  
    }  
 }

java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key input.error

Comment: Um, `extends java.util.PropertyResourceBundle`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4615268/823282 maybe this is what you wanted, but didn't know you wanted it

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class CombinedResourceBundle extends ResourceBundle
{
    private Map<String, String> combinedResources = new HashMap<>();
    private List<String> bundleNames;
    private Locale locale;
    private Control control;

    public CombinedResourceBundle(List<String> bundleNames, Locale locale, Control control)
    {
        this.bundleNames = bundleNames;
        this.locale = locale;
        this.control = control;
    }

    public void load()
    {
        bundleNames.forEach(bundleName ->
        {
            ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(bundleName, locale, control);
            Enumeration<String> keysEnumeration = bundle.getKeys();
            ArrayList<String> keysList = Collections.list(keysEnumeration);
            keysList.forEach(key -> combinedResources.put(key, bundle.getString(key)));
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Object handleGetObject(String key)
    {
        return combinedResources.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getKeys()
    {
        return Collections.enumeration(combinedResources.keySet());
    }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion the Control parameter is not needed (ResourceBundle contructor add one by default) except if you need a specific one. As the load() method is mandatory for this code to work, why don't you put his code in the constructor ? This will simplify code...

Answer (score 0):

ResourceBundle.Control() controls the list of files for the ResourceBundle. You can overwrite 
getCandidateLocales and toBundleName. toBundleName converts locale to the "file name" and the list of locales you can control in getCandidateLocales.
For example like

```
 final String[] variants = new String[]{"your names"};
 ResourceBundle.getBundle(baseName, locale,
            new ResourceBundle.Control() {
                public List<Locale> getCandidateLocales(String baseName, Locale locale) {

                        List<Locale> out = new ArrayList<Locale>();
                        String language = locale.getLanguage();
                        String country = locale.getCountry();

                        for (String variant : variants) {
                            out.add(new Locale(language, country, variant));
                        }
                        out.addAll(super.getCandidateLocales(baseName, locale));
                        return out;
                }

                public String toBundleName(String baseName, Locale locale) {
                        Locale l = new Locale(locale.getLanguage(), locale.getCountry());
                        return locale.getVariant() + "." + super.toBundleName(baseName, l);
                }
            });
```

It works only in Java 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Look at this class. It works for me perfectly! Javadoc for class explains how to use it.

[MultiplePropertiesResourceBundle](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dueni/faces-ext/master/resourcebundle/src/main/java/ch/dueni/util/MultiplePropertiesResourceBundle.java)
(+ subsidiary [ResourceBundleEnumeration](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dueni/faces-ext/master/resourcebundle/src/main/java/ch/dueni/util/ResourceBundleEnumeration.java))

Here you may find helpfull [unit-tests](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=faces-ext-master/resourcebundle/src/test/java/ch/dueni/util/MutliResourceBundleTest.java) a.k.a. code documentation.