# Is it possible to include resource bundle files within a resource bundle

Tags: java, resourcebundle

We are using `java.util.ResourceBundle` to load property information. Our property file has grown so huge and we are thinking of splitting the master property file into several sub modules. Is it possible to achieve this?

```
master.properties

==> 

 master.properties
   include moduleA.properties
   include moduleB.properties
```

Let me know?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, I wonder why you've chosen [`java.util.ResourceBundle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) over [`java.util.Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). Given how your question is formulated, you don't seem to care about localization/internationalization nor about bundle file inheritance.

With `Properties` it's extraordinary easy since it implements [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) which in turn offers a [`putAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29) method to merge another map. Kickoff example:

```
Properties master = new Properties();
master.load(masterInput);

Properties moduleA = new Properties();
moduleA.load(moduleAinput);
master.putAll(moduleA);

Properties moduleB = new Properties();
moduleB.load(moduleBinput);
master.putAll(moduleB);

// Now `master` contains the properties of all files.
```

If you really insist in using `ResourceBundle`, your best bet is to create a custom `ResourceBundle` wherein you contol the loading by a custom [`Control`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html).

Assuming that you've the following entry in `master.properties` which represents a commaseparated string with base names of the module properties files:

```
include=moduleA,moduleB
```

Then the following custom `ResourceBundle` example should work:

```
public class MultiResourceBundle extends ResourceBundle {

    protected static final Control CONTROL = new MultiResourceBundleControl();
    private Properties properties;

    public MultiResourceBundle(String baseName) {
        setParent(ResourceBundle.getBundle(baseName, CONTROL));
    }

    protected MultiResourceBundle(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
        return properties != null ? properties.get(key) : parent.getObject(key);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
        return properties != null ? (Enumeration<String>) properties.propertyNames() : parent.getKeys();
    }

    protected static class MultiResourceBundleControl extends Control {
        @Override
        public ResourceBundle newBundle(
            String baseName, Locale locale, String format, ClassLoader loader, boolean reload)
                throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, IOException
        {
            Properties properties = load(baseName, loader);
            String include = properties.getProperty("include");
            if (include != null) {
                for (String includeBaseName : include.split("\\s*,\\s*")) {
                    properties.putAll(load(includeBaseName, loader));
                }
            }
            return new MultiResourceBundle(properties);
        }

        private Properties load(String baseName, ClassLoader loader) throws IOException {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(loader.getResourceAsStream(baseName + ".properties"));
            return properties;
        }
    }

}
```

*(trivial exception handling and localization handling is left aside, this is up to you)*

This can be used as:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = new MultiResourceBundle("master");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can programatically, however, construct ResourceBundle but as you are saying your file is huge then what if it is loaded into memory.

**update**

```
public class Resource extends java.util.ResourceBundle {



    public Object handleGetObject(String key) {
         //code
    }

    public Enumeration getKeys() {
         //code
    }
}
```

then for IN locale

```
import java.util.*;

public class Resource_en_IN extends Resource{

  public Object handleGetObject(String key) {
    //code
  }
}
```

Comment: more painful to make all the modifications in a single file, the issue is with dev time and not with the runtime

Answer (score 1):

More Food for thought than a tested solution.

XML files support *entities* to inline text from other files during parsing. If seen complex xml files, where this technique has been used to modularise the files.

`Properties` now supports two file formats, the common `.properties` format with key/value pairs and an xml formats. `Properties` can load and store to/from xml files.

`ResourceBundle` has one direct subclass: `PropertyResourceBundle`. It looks like this class is actually limited to the older key/value pair format, but it could be used to implement another class, like `XMLPropertyResourceBundle` which is capable of reading properties from xml files where the `entity` trick could help to modularize those files.

If this works - transforming the existing property files to xml properties files should be easy, just use the `Properties` class, read from standard format and store to XML.