# How to load jasperreports resourcebundle at runtime?

Tags: internationalization, jasper-reports

Is it possible with `jasper Reports` to load a `ResourceBundle` (for `i18n`) at runtime?

I want to create a report from a jrxml file (for example `c:\reports\report.jrxml`)
with my labels in the properties file located at (`c:\messages\report.properties`).

I only found example where the property file is in the classloader.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[John Ferguson's blog](http://www.jroller.com/wakaleo/entry/jasperreports_tip_using_localized_resources) mentions that the trick is to override the `REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE` parameter with a custom ResourceBundle instance.

```
// Compiling the report is not a necessary step; prefer using .jasper files
// that have been pre-compiled to avoid this compilation step.
//
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JasperManager.loadXmlDesign("Report.jrxml");
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("REPORT_LOCALE",LocaleManager.currentLocale());
parameters.put("REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE",resourceBundle);
Connection conn = DBConnectionFactory.getConnection();
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
                                                       parameters,
                                                       conn);
```

The `resourceBundle` can come from anywhere. For example:

```
try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/tmp/report.properties")) {
  ResourceBundle resourceBundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(fis);

  // Pass resourceBundle into the report, as shown above.
}
```

Comment: To emulate resource bundle inheritance, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4615268/59087

Answer (score 3):

loading  bundle from resources package:

```
ResourceBundle bundle=ResourceBundle.getBundle("/reports/bundles/bundle",Locale.CANADA_FRENCH);
```

filling report::

```
 params.put("REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE", bundle);
JasperPrint jasPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportStream, params, data);
```