# JavaFX 2 and Internationalization loading properties files

Tags: java, javafx-2, resourcebundle, properties-file

how to load multiple ResourceBundle files i have multiple fxml files and for every file i created a properties file eg: top.fxml top.properties how to load all the properties files ?

I try something like that but its not working

```
    Locale locale = new Locale("fr", "FR");
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n.bottom", locale);
    ResourceBundle bundle2 = ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n.top", locale);

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
    loader.setResources(bundle);
    loader.setResources(bundle2);
    Parent root = loader.load();
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try it, but it should just be as simple as setting the bundle each time before you load:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
loader.setResources(bundle);
Parent firstBundleRoot = loader.load();
loader.setResources(bundle2);
Parent secondBundleRoot = loader.load();
```

Note that this assumes that what you are trying to do is generate multiple node trees for the different bundles, each of which is customized by different bundle text (which may not be what you want).

I do get the feeling that I may have missed something in your question...

---

Perhaps you are trying to do the following?

- [Java Multiple ResourceBundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630339/java-multiple-resourcebundles)
- [Is it possible to include resource bundle files within a resource bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614465/is-it-possible-to-include-resource-bundle-files-within-a-resource-bundle)

Which I think is a solution to create some kind of mega-resource bundle that includes merged resources from various resource bundles.  So, if this is the case, rather than loading each bundle separately and loading the FXML each time, resulting in multiple root panes (as the previous part of this answer suggests), you could first merge the bundles, then load the FXML a single time resulting in a single root pane.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
loader.setResources(merge(bundle1, bundle2));
Parent root = loader.load();
```

Where `merge(bundle1, bundle2)` is some function which you develop yourself based upon the answers in the linked questions.

Comment: thanks i need to try but the second solution seems to be a good one